# How to get exit status of anacron jobs to catch errors?

Tags: log, anacron

It is easy to find failed cron jobs by setting log_level but how to do it with anacron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get exit status from syslog.

To get all anacron log lines:

```
grep 'anacron' /var/log/syslog
```

To get only anacron log lines from failed jobs:

```
grep -E 'anacron.*exit status' /var/log/syslog
```